# How to terminate TeamViewer application from Mac OS Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, teamviewer, kill

I have tried terminating TeamViewer application from the Mac OS terminal using the following command. It kills the app but again it starts automatically in the very next second. How can can I terminate it completely without popping up again?

Command used

`ps aux | grep -i teamviewer | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pkill  command.
Run

```
pkill teamviewer
```

This will find all processes with name Teamviewer and kill from the terminal.

This is basically a combination of pgrep and kill command, find and kill.

Comment: It doesn't work.